# Measure cache memory usage

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to call a function and measure the amount of Data cache memory the function used. Are there any procedures to that in C or C++, or any libraries in Linux based systems?

To measure time it was like

```
start = timestamp();
proc()
end = timestamp();
proctime = end - start;
```

Comment: it would have to be something built into the cache and how do you isolate your cache usage vs the usage of all the other software running in your system.

Comment: it would have to be something built into the cache and how do you isolate your cache usage vs the usage of all the other software running in your system.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Without simulating the processor, it probably can't be done.

Long answer:

In user-mode, in any modern OS, you won't be able to get that sort of data. You can use `oprofile` or `perf` to get cache hit & miss numbers - unfortunately, it won't exactly tell you how much is caused by your process and how much is in other processes in the system (since the processor counters that the processor has are global, and the tool doesn't know when a process is switched in/out, only "which process is running when the counter got to the trigger value").

In other words, this will give statistics, not actual numbers of exactly what you want to measure. Also, it won't actually tell you if you use 1% or 100% of the cache, just how much data you are using that is in the cache, compared to how much data is NOT in the cache - if you are REALLY clever, you could probably write something that gets 95% cache misses, but only uses a small number of cache-lines [but it would take some working on actually using exactly the right address in one or more blocks of memory that has N*cache_size distance between them].

It is however a very much workable model for figuring out "does my code have a cache-miss problem".

I'm not aware of any method to actually do what you want, besides the extreme method of:

1. Place the code inside a kernel module.
2. Disable all interrupts.
3. Set up perf counters to count cache hit/miss for data L1, L2, etc.
4. Run the function you want to test.
5. Collect results.

That becomes hugely unpractical, since the code won't be able to do any I/O or access memory that is swapped out, as well as the OS will probably get upset if interrupts are off for longer than a few milliseconds...

Link to "perf" project for Linux kernel:
https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page
If you have a reasonably new kernel, this would be your ideal tool for measuring performance in general.